# The map between the managed property and crawl property is not shown correctly when i access the relation from the managed property

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-property, crawled-property

I have a managed property named "SoftwareDevelopmentOWSUser" inside our SharePoint online tenant, and when i access the managed property i can see that it is not associated with any crawled property, as follow:-
[image]

While if i access the crawl property i can see that it is associated with the above managed property, as follow:-
[image]

so which screen is valid? and why i am getting confusion results?

Answer (score 1):

From the official article: The search schema displays the name of auto-generated managed properties and their mappings to crawled properties in grey in the search schema. The search schema doesn't hold the settings of the managed auto-generated managed properties. The settings exist, but they're hidden from the search schema.

Manage the search schema in SharePoint Online for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-search-schema

Comment: thanks for the replay, but can you explain you answer in more details ?

Comment: It is by designer that the managed property mappings to crawled property. But they're hidden from the search schema.

Comment: so to know which crawl property is mapped to a managed property then i need to start the search from the Crawl Property section?

Comment: Yes. Or you can add the mapping in managed property manually.